# Unable to access a specific variable inside a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, aggregate, assign

Consider this " for loop"

```
alpha <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:30)
{
 nam <- paste("d", i, sep = "")
 assign(nam,  filter(a1,day(date)==i))
 nam <- aggregate(steps~group,nam,sum()) #I want to access d[i] through variable "nam" which is showing error
alpha <- rbind(alpha,nam) 
}
```

In each iteration of for loop, I want to filter 'days' (varying 1 to 30), and use aggregate function for grouping according to column group and finally rbind each iteration to create a new data frame alpha

But this brings up this error for line 3 inside for loop

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

My dataframe "a1"

```
 tibble: 8,640 x 5
   steps date       interval interval.1          group
   <dbl> <fct>         <int> <dttm>              <fct>
 1     0 2012-11-01        0 2012-11-01 00:00:00 0    
 2     0 2012-11-01        5 2012-11-01 00:05:00 0    
 3     0 2012-11-01       10 2012-11-01 00:10:00 0    
 4     0 2012-11-01       15 2012-11-01 00:15:00 0    
 5     0 2012-11-01       20 2012-11-01 00:20:00 0    
 6     0 2012-11-01       25 2012-11-01 00:25:00 0    
 7     0 2012-11-01       30 2012-11-01 00:30:00 0    
 8     0 2012-11-01       35 2012-11-01 00:35:00 0    
 9     0 2012-11-01       40 2012-11-01 00:40:00 0    
10     0 2012-11-01       45 2012-11-01 00:45:00 0    
# ... with 8,630 more rows
```

Please explain me a way of resolving this? Any answer for reaching my desired output would be suffice

**EDIT -1**

dput(head(a1,10))=

```
structure(list(steps = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), date = structure(c(32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), .Label = c("2012-10-01", 
"2012-10-02", "2012-10-03", "2012-10-04", "2012-10-05", "2012-10-06", 
"2012-10-07", "2012-10-08", "2012-10-09", "2012-10-10", "2012-10-11", 
"2012-10-12", "2012-10-13", "2012-10-14", "2012-10-15", "2012-10-16", 
"2012-10-17", "2012-10-18", "2012-10-19", "2012-10-20", "2012-10-21", 
"2012-10-22", "2012-10-23", "2012-10-24", "2012-10-25", "2012-10-26", 
"2012-10-27", "2012-10-28", "2012-10-29", "2012-10-30", "2012-10-31", 
"2012-11-01", "2012-11-02", "2012-11-03", "2012-11-04", "2012-11-05", 
"2012-11-06", "2012-11-07", "2012-11-08", "2012-11-09", "2012-11-10", 
"2012-11-11", "2012-11-12", "2012-11-13", "2012-11-14", "2012-11-15", 
"2012-11-16", "2012-11-17", "2012-11-18", "2012-11-19", "2012-11-20", 
"2012-11-21", "2012-11-22", "2012-11-23", "2012-11-24", "2012-11-25", 
"2012-11-26", "2012-11-27", "2012-11-28", "2012-11-29", "2012-11-30"
), class = "factor"), interval = c(0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 
30L, 35L, 40L, 45L), interval.1 = structure(c(1351708200, 1351708500, 
1351708800, 1351709100, 1351709400, 1351709700, 1351710000, 1351710300, 
1351710600, 1351710900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("0", "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", 
    "700", "800", "900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300", "1400", 
    "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800", "1900", "2000", "2100", "2200", 
    "2300"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please read `?assign` first. In any case, what exactly is your desired output? Is there any reason you want to use an explicit loop?

Comment: Forget that `assign` exists. Learn to use lists instead.

Comment: This is what I expect to do @NelsonGon: In each iteration of for loop, I want to filter 'days' (varying 1 to 30), and use aggregate function for grouping according to column group and finally rbind each iteration to create a new data frame alpha

Comment: How do I that? @Roland.... Can you please brief your answer, which would be very helpful

Comment: Could you add the output of `dput(head(df,10))` to your question?

Comment: `aggregate(steps ~ group + day(date), data=a1, FUN=sum)`

Comment: I have added @NelsonGon,,,, please check now!!!!

Comment: Please take a look at how to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You've used `dput`, but what you've given us doesn't really look representative of your data because there's only one value each for `steps`, `date` and `group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the data based on `date` and then `aggregate` for each group.

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(a1, a1$date), function(x) aggregate(steps~group,x,sum))
```

This should give you list of dataframes for each date with `sum` of `steps` by `group` . You can access individual dataframe by doing `lst1[[1]]`, `lst1[[2]]`.

---

To get output in one dataframe, we can use `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(a1, a1$date), function(x) aggregate(steps~group,x,sum)))
```

Comment: This works....but becomes difficult to work on further as a whole. I want all the lists to be coerced into single data frame. I tried the same using: df1 <- sapply(lst1,function(x) rbind(alpha,lst1[[x]])) @Ronak Shah Please help me here?

Comment: @AnanyaVidyanathan We can use `do.call`. Updated the answer.

Comment: @AnanyaVidyanathan ohh..wait if you want everything again in single dataframe. Wouldn't it be just `aggregate(steps~group + date, x, sum)` then?

Comment: But I want to have interval.1 column also included in my final dataframe, but in the aggregate function, we will only get "steps" and "groups" column. I also tried that using aggregate```(steps ~ cbind(group + day(interval.1),interval.1), data=a1, FUN=sum) ``` @Ronak Do you get what I ask?

Comment: @AnanyaVidyanathan there are different `interval.1` values for each group which one would you like to select? Maybe if you want to keep the maximum value `a1 %>%
  group_by(group, date) %>%
  mutate(steps = sum(steps)) %>%
  slice(which.max(interval.1))`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using dplyr anyway you can use `summarise` instead of `aggregate`, which can simplify things quite a bit. Given a dataframe like this (note that I've left out some irrelevant variables):

```r
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   steps interval            group
   <int> <dttm>              <int>
 1     1 2012-11-01 00:00:00     1
 2     4 2012-11-01 00:05:00     1
 3     4 2012-11-01 00:10:00     1
 4     5 2012-11-01 00:15:00     1
 5     6 2012-11-01 00:20:00     1
 6     6 2012-11-01 00:25:00     2
 7     6 2012-11-01 00:30:00     2
 8     7 2012-11-01 00:35:00     2
 9     9 2012-11-01 00:40:00     2
10    10 2012-11-01 00:45:00     2
# … with 20 more rows
```

Do the following, which groups by `date` and `group`, and then computes a summary (sum of `steps` in this case) for each:

```r
df %>% 
    group_by(date = date(interval), group) %>% 
    summarize(sum = sum(steps))
```

Which will produce something like this:

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   date [3]
  date       group   sum
  <date>     <int> <int>
1 2012-11-01     1    20
2 2012-11-01     2    38
3 2012-11-02     1    14
4 2012-11-02     2    42
5 2012-11-03     1    12
6 2012-11-03     2    38
```

The major benefits here are clarity, and the fact that you can compute the group sums without having to stack the dataframes afterwards. Alternatively you can also use something like `aggregate(steps ~ group + date(interval), df, sum)` or `aggregate(df$steps, by = list(group = df$group, date = date(df$interval)), sum)` if you want to stick to base R, which are also pretty concise options in this particular case.

#### Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(steps = c(1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L), interval = structure(c(1351728000, 
1351728300, 1351728600, 1351728900, 1351729200, 1351729500, 1351729800, 
1351730100, 1351730400, 1351730700, 1351814400, 1351814700, 1351815000, 
1351815300, 1351815600, 1351815900, 1351816200, 1351816500, 1351816800, 
1351817100, 1351900800, 1351901100, 1351901400, 1351901700, 1351902000, 
1351902300, 1351902600, 1351902900, 1351903200, 1351903500), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Yeah Man  @gersht ....I exactly get what you are coming to say .....But it shows up this error in my code```Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied```

Comment: @AnanyaVidyanathan I'm sure it has to do with `date(interval)`. If you look at my `dput` output you'll see `tzone = "UTC"`, while in your output you'll see `tzone = ""`, i.e. no timezone. It's unlikely that my synthetic data is a perfect representation of your real data (thus the importance of giving us a representative sample of your real data). You can either give your `interval` column a timezone, or, since you already have a `date` variable (as a factor), you can just use that instead - i.e. just `date` instead of `date(interval)` or `date(df$interval)`.